# "Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParse.Exception"

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

WinRT information: Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as 'HorizontalContentAlignment' was not found in type 'null'.[Line: 0 Position: 0]

No additional information.

This error appears when I transfer my project from visual studio 2013 pro (Lenovo, Windows 10) to visual studio community 2015 (Dell, Windows 8.1). It occurs within the constructor item detail page.

Debugging thus far: 
Inner Exception: null, "Text associated with this error code not be found"

If I delete my edited copy of ListViewItemStyle it gives no errors.

If I add a copy of ListViewItemStyle without editing it, I still get an error.

If I delete one line of code either in the xaml item page or xaml.cs item page and add it back in immediately, it gives no error.

I have also tried adding the style to the listview instead of the listview items, still gives error.

I am concerned with this because I don't want to release the app and have it glich out.

Here's the code:

```
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"    
Loaded="Research_Loaded"
xmlns:xc="using:ColorPicker"
NavigationCacheMode="Disabled">
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="selectedColor" Color="YellowGreen"/>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,18,2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" ContentMargin="4" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" PointerOverBackgroundMargin="1" PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource selectedColor}" SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True" SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" SelectedBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness}" SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    DataContext="{Binding Item}"
    d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[0].Items[0], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/layOut.json, Type=data:DataSource}}" SizeChanged="image_SizeChanged">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".8*" MinHeight="500"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".1*" MinHeight="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,50,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button" Click="leavePage_Event_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1"
            IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,48" FontWeight="Medium"/>
    </Grid>

    <!-- THIS IS THE MIDDLE REGION OF THE PAGE                     -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="contentRegion">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" MinHeight="520"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".17*" MinWidth="240" MaxWidth="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".13*" MinWidth="175" MaxWidth="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*" MinWidth="510"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".13*" MinWidth="175" MaxWidth="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".17*" MinWidth="240" MaxWidth="300"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- USED FOR COLOR DIFFERENTIAL   -->

                <Button x:Name="seg" FontSize="24" Content="Body" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <Flyout Placement="Right">
                            <ListView x:Name="segMenu" SelectionMode="Multiple" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Width="210" ItemClick="segment_Button_Click">
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Full Bod" Tag="25" Width="190" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Clear" Tag="26" Width="190"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Hair"  Tag="0" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Eyes"  Tag="1" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Fingers"  Tag="2" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Back"  Tag="3" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Front"  Tag="4" Width="190"  IsSelected="True" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Side"  Tag="5" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Side"  Tag="11" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Elbow"  Tag="6" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Elbow"  Tag="12" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  "  Tag="7" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right "  Tag="13" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Hand"  Tag="8" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Hand"  Tag="14" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Hand"  Tag="9" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Hand"  Tag="15" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Thumb"  Tag="10" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Thumb"  Tag="16" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Hip"  Tag="17" Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Hip"  Tag="21"  Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Knee Cap"  Tag="18"  Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Knee Cap"  Tag="22"  Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Ankle"  Tag="19"  Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Ankle"  Tag="23"  Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Left  Toe"  Tag="20"  Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                                <ListViewItem Content=" Right Toe"  Tag="24"  Width="190"  IsSelected="True"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
                            </ListView>
                        </Flyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>


    </Grid>
```

Comment: When I make an executable and run it on the Windows 8.1 pc it won't let me enter this page, but if I transfer the project to the Windows 8.1 pc and delete any line, then add it back in and make excutable with visual studio community 2015 it works.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is having the problem above I have found a solution. I was editing a copy template of ListViewItem. Instead, one should go to the definition of listViewItemExpanded and copy that template. You then can make edits from there and it no longer throws exceptions when transferring an executable from windows 10 to windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Once you make an executable, it will run the same on every computer (as long as it's the same architecture). You need not worry about it glitching out (at least with a compilation error like the one you're talking about).

There is a difference between a compilation error and a runtime error.

Comment: I would like to understand then when I've made an executable it doesn't work on 8.1. Also, when I transfer the project to windows 8.1 and run it in visual studio community it will say the error stated above. Yet, if I delete any line within the code and and replace it, the program works without errors... Thank you for your response.